# Angular directive not checked

Tags: angularjs

How can I get the following checkbox to be checked or not based on a "bindto" attribute?  I've tried `element.checked = true` and it didn't check the checkbox.  Any suggestions?

```
directive('slideToggle', function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            bindto: '='
        },
        template: '<input type="checkbox" name=""/>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope); //shows scope.bindto as "true"
            console.log(scope.bindto); //undefined
        }
    }
}).
```

usage:

`<slide-toggle bindTo="myItem.active"></slide-toggle>`

Comment: is the template supposed to have bindTo camelcase and the directive bindto all lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bindto is initially undefined, since the directive is linked before the scope is updated by the parent controller. You need to listen for a change in scope:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch("bindto", function (newValue) {
        console.log(scope.bindto); //undefined
    });
}
```

It appears as "true" in your console on "scope" since the time it took for you to click into the "scope" object was long enough for it to be updated.

Comment: While this is correct, I also needed to use `ng-model` as suggested by @Ajay

Answer (score 2):

You should be using ng-model property on the checkbox see the updated code

```
  <body ng-controller="test" >
          <input ng-model="myItem.active" />
       <slide-toggle bindto="myItem.active"></slide-toggle>
          <script>
              var app = angular.module('customControl', [])
              app.controller('test', function ($scope) {
                  $scope.userContent = 'hello';
                  $scope.myItem = { active: true };


              });

              app.directive('slideToggle', function () {
                  return {
                      replace: true,
                      restrict: 'E',
                      scope: {
                          bindto: '=bindto'
                      },
                      template: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model= "bindto"/>',
                      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                      }
                  }
              })
```